# castle's defensive architecture terminology

Tags: meaning, differences, architecture

what is difference between **battlement,parapet,crenellations,ramparts** they all seem same to me,something that is used for guarding castle.please shed some light on this.please try and use images if possible

i have googled for it and didn't find any difference

i have to know the nuances of this, because currently, i am reading George R.R. martin's widely acclaimed epic fantasy 'A song of ice and fire'...

thanks in advance

Comment: http://medievalcastles.stormthecastle.com/parts-of-a-medieval-castle.htm

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I hope this helps.
**Rampart**: *A defensive wall of a castle or walled city, having a broad top with a walkway.* 
[image: Rampart]
**Parapet**: *A protective wall or earth defense along the top of a trench or other place of concealment for troops.*
**Battlement**: *A type of parapet on top of a defending rampart to provide cover, with square openings used t*o train and discharge crossbows.
[image: Battlement]
**Crenellation**: *Another word for battlement, or for the technique of providing spaced crossbow openings.*

In other words: A castle wall is a **rampart**. A lesser defending wall, such as a fence, is a **parapet**. A protective stone parapet on top of a rampart with crossbow grooves and openings is a **battlement**. A battlement is the same thing as a **crenellation**.

Oxford American College Dictionary.